# Use OpenID Connect Gluu authentication provider to secure Spring Boot Web App client

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, openid-connect

I have followed this guide http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2 and can get it to work with Facebook and Github but I want to use GLuu as my in house authentication provider to do OpenID Connect with my spring boot web app. I have Gluu configured to return two response types both 
Authorization Code Grant Type and
ID Token  and I have the authentication method set to client_secret_basic.  I'm not sure what additional configuration I have to do on the spring client web app side but I would think based on the guide I could do a minimal configuration and just set

security.oauth2.client.client-id=

security.oauth2.client.client-secret=

security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://mygluuServer/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/token

security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://mygluuServer/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/authorize

security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://mygluuServer/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/userinfo

security.oauth2.client.scope=openid

When I navigate to my spring boot web app i get redirected to gluu for authentication but after I authenticate it doesn't prompt me to approve the sharing of my openid info it just redirects me back to the spring boot app and give me the error.. Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token

Has anyone had any success using Gluu to secure a spring boot web app using OpenID Connect?

Comment: After having turned up the logging to trace level on the spring boot side I am starting to see what the problem is but I'm not sure how to resolve it.  The /oxauth/authorize endpoint is called without error and Gluu sends back an authorization code and session_ID.  The problem is when Spring calls back to the oxauth/token end point... here is the error

Comment: 2016-01-14 12:20:31.339 DEBUG 6987 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[09140630-c1d1-42c4-a5fa-354609cad5ab], redirect_uri=[https://magellan:8443/login], client_id=[@!1565.489B.E582.E70F!0001!156A.784D!0008!922A.2F73], client_secret=[superSecret]}
2016-01-14 12:20:31.351 DEBUG 6987 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
201

Comment: So if I understand correctly after authenticating with Gluu after the first redirect the browser get's a cookie so the browser is authenticated to Gluu but Spring Boot Client is not.  After authenticating to Gluu, Gluu redirects back to spring boot /login url with the auth_code and session_id then spring boot does a post to /oxauth/token endpoint but I think it's getting blocked because spring boot client hasn't authenticated to Gluu.  Shouldn't the /oxauth/token endpoint be open to all requests and not require authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out what my problem was.  For some reason the BadCredentialsException was masking the real error which was that Java didn't want to talk to Gluu over a secure connection to the token endpoint because java didn't trust the Gluu certificate.  With Gluu in client_secret_post authentication mode and  my spring boot client using the properties

security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=form

security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form

everything works great now that I have imported the Gluu certificate into my jvm's cacerts java keystore.  I'd like to just import it into a truststore and point to it with my application.properties but am currently having issues with that.

Comment: Hello @emmmdeee, I have a similar issue. I'm trying to authenticate with Spring Boot and WSO2 Identity Server

Comment: Ok that's pretty vague.  I would say that if you're getting an error and you can't figure out the base cause try to configure your Identity server to only work on http (if it will let you) then watch the traffic in wireshark while the process flow happens.  It may give you a clue.   If you have to run over https you probably definitely need to export the WSO2 certificate and import it into the cacerts file of the JVM that your spring boot app is running on.  This is required because by default Java won't make successful post requests to servers that it doesn't trust the certificate for.